# Jenkins pipeline to verify files existence in specific format inside when condition

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I need to verify whether any file exists in .doc format in a specific directory. based on which when the condition will be executed.

i.e) when a file found inside a directory with the .doc extension it should proceed to execute steps.

Below code is unable to find the files in .doc format

```
        when {
            expression
            { 
               return (fileExists("""${Path}/${version}/test/*.doc"""))
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [findFiles](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-findfiles-code-find-files-in-the-workspace), fileExists doesn't support wildcards.

```
when {
    expression { 
       return (findFiles(glob: "${Path}/${version}/test/*.doc").length > 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: How this will be included in when condition? is these findfiles will be declared outside when ?

Comment: you are really awesome :)