# Jenkins check if file exists in the path using asterisks

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am very new to Groovy and Jenkins. I am trying to check if file exists on generalize path something like this:

```
when {
   expression { return (fileExists("*service/target/test-classes") }
}
```

In my path, I have generalized path like `app-study-service` or `app-share-service`, then I create target folder with test-classes folder.

I want Jenkins to trigger steps step after this when condition if there is file in that path. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why it wasn't working. It is because fileExists does not support wildcards. I would need to use without wildcard or use something that supports wildcards, such as findFiles.

[Jenkins pipeline to verify files existence in specific format inside when condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043894/jenkins-pipeline-to-verify-files-existence-in-specific-format-inside-when-condit)